# Usage of Firebase for Google Auth in Firefox extension

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firefox-addon

I'm trying to use Firebase for Google Authentification in Mozilla Firefox extension. 
However, it throws this error:
`This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.`

After some researching i figured out:

1) Firefox extensions not supported by Firebase.

2) Adding of `moz-extension://` doesn't work.

Here is some links to related questions:

- [Firebase Auth with Firefox Web Extension Add On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518887/firebase-auth-with-firefox-web-extension-add-on)
- https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/moz-extension-protocol-is-not-accepted-by-firebase-any-workarounds/32570

Any workarounds at the moment? It has been one year since the problem was discovered... I need to use exactly Firebase for authentification, because it shares common DB.